# statement in sql

Tags: sql

There are rows. They are separated by a comma-separated values. How do I bring only one example. (1) My solution does not work.

```
SELECT VB.COL    
FROM (SELECT '21,31' AS COL
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '1' AS COL
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '21,31,1' AS COL
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '156,158' AS COL
      FROM DUAL
     ) VB           
WHERE VB.COL  LIKE '%'||1||'%';
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I think its ORACLE database

Comment: Can you describe required out put in form of a output table?

Answer (score 0):

Storing lists of numbers as a comma-separated string is a bad, bad idea.  It is not the SQL way of storing lists.  If you have any control over the database, then create a proper junction table.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  In that case, you can use `LIKE`, but you should include the delimiters:

```
WHERE ',' || VB.COL || ','  LIKE '%,' || 1 || ',%';
```

The delimiters prevent "1" from matching "31" and "21".

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to bring output string where only '1' is available.
Please let me know if i am wrong. because not able to understand your required output. I will change query accordingly if required.

```
SELECT VB.COL    
FROM (SELECT '21,31' AS COL
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL 
SELECT '1' AS COL
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '21,31,1' AS COL
FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '156,158' AS COL
FROM DUAL
) VB           
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE (VB.COL,'^1$');
```